# how to update externel json file using js

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file called *`items.json`* in same directory, with fields `id,name and place` .I have 3 variables like `var a, var b, var c` with values which are to be updated in `items.json`file. How can i update it?

JSON sample given below:

```
 "items": [
   {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "edison",
    "place": "wayanad"
   }
 ]
```

how to update `var b` to `edison` and `var c` to `wayanad`

Comment: var b = items[0].name ???, and same with rest vars?

Comment: you can't change server files with only client-side code, you must have some service on your server that will save the file for you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón is it possible to push values by creating an array..?

Comment: @Edison, as i supose from your question. First create an array and then make a push. And then yes is possible

Comment: This is only possible with server-side code as JavaScript is not able to write data back to the file. Of course you can read and manipulate the data to display the value's etc. with client-side code but nothing will be updated. Consider node.js to use JavaScript on the server.